# Test if a variable is a component or Boolean

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to figure out how I can test if the function of a component has returned a component or Boolean false.

For example a component's find method like

```
<cfset hotel = oHotel.findById(1200) />
<cfif  hotel >
 ...
</cfif>
```

If a hotel is found then a component is returned, otherwise false.
Is it generally OK to write such code, or should I write to the `cfif` another way?

Comment: Why not return an empty query and check for a record count?

Comment: What does findById() return?

Comment: You should probably rethink. I don't think you want a method that returns a boolean OR an object. It should be more predictable. Use "findByID()" to send you a true or false and create a separate getHotelObj()   (or whatever) to give you back your bean or component. Your logic code should always be the most readable/understandable of your various code blocks IMO.

Comment: I agree with Mark A Kruger. Re-think what you want and return. Still if you don't have control on what gets returned then [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208155/coldfusion-get-variable-type) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, [`IsSimpleValue()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/issimplevalue.html) can be used to determine if the variable is...a simple value. That is, *not* an array, struct, query, or component.

> **Returns**
>   True, if value is a string, number, Boolean, or date/time value; False, otherwise.

```
<cfset hotel = oHotel.findById(1200) />
<cfif  IsSimpleValue(hotel)>
  <!--- it is a simple value, i.e., NOT a component --->
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `IsValid()` function as follows

```
<cfset hotel = oHotel.findById(1200) />

<cfif IsValid("component",hotel)> //Hotel found
    <!--- Code to perform if it is Component --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- Code to perform if it is not a Component --->
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<cfif isBoolean( hotel )>
    ....
</cfif>
```

However, I would suggest making `findById()` return `NULL` if there is no hotel with the matching ID. Then you would use

```
<cfif !isNull( hotel )>
    ....
</cfif>
```