# Unexpected behaviour of int()

Tags: coldfusion, int, rounding, coldfusion-10

I'm a bit confused about following behaviour of the `int()`-function in ColdFusion 10 (10,0,20,282462):

```
<cfset dummy = 100 - (5859 / (6510 / 100)) />
<cfoutput>
    dummy = #dummy#<br><br> <!--- 10 --->
    int(10) = #int(10)#<br> <!--- 10 --->
    int(dummy) = #int(dummy)# <!--- 9 --->
</cfoutput>
```

Can anybody explain me why `int(dummy)` returns 9 instead of 10?

Comment: dummy is actually a float.  It's simply getting displayed as an integer.  Output it with a number format to see the real value.

Comment: To confirm that it a float, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208155/coldfusion-get-variable-type

Comment: Maybe round and then use Javacast?  This will return 10.  <cfset dummy = Javacast("int", round(100 - (5859 / (6510 / 100)))) >

Comment: As with most numbers, CF stores the result of the division an approximate type: java.lang.Double and [decimal numbers that "look" round in base 10, are not exactly representable in base 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2002837/104223). In this case [the real value is ~ 9.999999999999986](http://trycf.com/gist/4e8e89c5799fd1e13c490dddaae70b82/acf?theme=monokai), which when rounded down equals 9, not 10.

Answer (score 0):

`int(dummy)` returns `9` instead of `10` because it is essentially `floor()` in other languages, and your answer may become `9` because for performance, by default, they are treated as `double`.

Have you heard of `PrecisionEvaluate()` https://cfdocs.org/precisionevaluate

```
dummy = PrecisionEvaluate(100 - (5859 / (6510 / 100)));
writeOutput(dummy);
```

you'll get `10` as expected