# Typed array vs untyped array in ColdFusion

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2018

I have the following code:

```
<cfscript>
data = ['2342bas', 'asqwerewq', '12314', 12421, 1.1];

newdata = arrayNew['Numeric'](1);

for (item in data)  {
    newdata.append(val(item));
    }

writedump(newdata); 


newdata = [];

for (item in data)  {
    newdata.append(val(item));
    }

writedump(newdata);  
</cfscript>
```

I am getting the following results:

[image]

I am wondering why they are different. Does 'Number' force all the data to be floating point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the answer I had to dive into the meta data

```
<cfscript>
data = ['2342bas', 'asqwerewq', '12314', 12421, 1.1];

newdata = arrayNew['Numeric'](1);

for (item in data)  {
    newdata.append(val(item));
    }

newdata.each(function(value) {
    writeoutput("<br /><b>#value#</b> #getMetadata(value).getName()#");
    });

writeoutput("<hr />");


newdata = [];

for (item in data)  {
    newdata.append(val(item));
    }

newdata.each(function(value) {
    writeoutput("<br /><b>#value#</b> #getMetadata(value).getName()#");
    });
</cfscript>
```

**Results**

[image]

It is interesting that BigDecimal always has a decimal and Double may or may not. Based on this question, [ColdFusion: Get variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208155/coldfusion-get-variable-type/58470285) , I never knew their was a way to use a BigDecimal in ColdFusion.

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion often has numeric values as `java.lang.Double` data types. It is likely doing a cast on each value to `java.lang.Double` as part of the append.

Comment: @Alex he is running a val() on the value before appending. https://cfdocs.org/val

Comment: `val` maybe converts to number (removes characters) but the array still stores as a `variant` type. array['numeric'] eventually stores as double. When you use `cfqueryparam cf_sql_numeric` you see in the debug output that all numbers are passed as float/double into the database.